# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'insert' while writting Tkinter GUI for Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```py
#So after clicking for ex. button with "5" fucnction has to write 5 on calc

import tkinter as tk

symbols=["7", "8", "9", "/", "\u21BA","4", "5", "6", "*", "C", "1", "2", "3", "-", "x^2", "0", "+", "\u221A"]

def window():
    root=tk.Tk()

    root.configure(bg="light gray")

    root.geometry('460x430')

    root.title("Kalkurator ONP")

    return root

def screen(root):

    screen=[tk.Label(root, width=65, anchor="w", borderwidth=2, bg='#C0CBCB') for i in range(3)]

    for i in range(len(screen)):

        #ipadx and ipady are margins
        screen[i].grid(row=i, columnspan=5, ipady=15, ipadx=1)

    return screen

def dataLabel(root, screen):
    label_for_data=tk.Entry(root, borderwidth=0, highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white")
    label_for_data.grid(row=len(screen), columnspan=5, ipadx=160, ipady=10)

    info=tk.Label(root, width=65, anchor="w", borderwidth=2, bg='white')
    info.grid(row=len(screen)+1, columnspan=5, ipady=15, ipadx=1)

    return label_for_data, info

def afterClickingBtn(lfd, symbol):
    def f():
        lfd.insert(tk.END, symbol)#Here is the problem
    return f

def buttons(root, screen):

    j=len(screen)+2

    button=[tk.Button(root, text=symbol, bg="light gray", borderwidth=0) for symbol in symbols]
    for i in range(len(symbols)):
        if i%5==0:
            j+=1
        button[i].grid(row=j, column=i%5, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
        button[i].configure(command=afterClickingBtn(dataLabel, button[i]["text"]))

    equal_button=tk.Button(root, text="=", bg="green", borderwidth=0)
    equal_button.grid(row=len(screen)+6, column=3, columnspan=2, ipadx=60, ipady=10)

    return button, equal_button
    

def main():
    root=window()

    sc=screen(root)

    lfd=dataLabel(root, sc)
    
    btn=buttons(root, sc)

    #End of loop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code, and include the full error in the body of your question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate with the `afterClickingBtn` function that's what they want since the returned value is a function. As for `dataLabel` I'm sure they want that function, they just forgot to specify `lfd[0]` when interacting with the label itself as the function returns a tuple

Answer (score 0):

So, just 2 small things.

1. `lfd` is a tuple, what you want to use `insert` on is `lfd[0]` (your `label_for_data` object).
2. You should pass `lfd` from function to function if you're going to take this approach, so the `buttons` function needs to be passed `lfd`

For me, this code works (adjustments are at the `lfdClickingButton` function and onwards):

```
import tkinter as tk

symbols = [
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "/",
    "\u21BA",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "*",
    "C",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "-",
    "x^2",
    "0",
    "+",
    "\u221A",
]


def window():
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.configure(bg="light gray")

    root.geometry("460x430")

    root.title("Kalkurator ONP")

    return root


def screen(root):

    screen = [
        tk.Label(root, width=65, anchor="w", borderwidth=2, bg="#C0CBCB")
        for i in range(3)
    ]

    for i in range(len(screen)):

        # ipadx and ipady are margins
        screen[i].grid(row=i, columnspan=5, ipady=15, ipadx=1)

    return screen


def dataLabel(root, screen):
    label_for_data = tk.Entry(
        root, borderwidth=0, highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white"
    )
    label_for_data.grid(row=len(screen), columnspan=5, ipadx=160, ipady=10)

    info = tk.Label(root, width=65, anchor="w", borderwidth=2, bg="white")
    info.grid(row=len(screen) + 1, columnspan=5, ipady=15, ipadx=1)

    return label_for_data, info


def afterClickingBtn(lfd, symbol):
    def f():
        # Use insert method on lfd[0], not lfd
        lfd[0].insert(tk.END, symbol)

    return f


def buttons(root, screen, lfd):

    j = len(screen) + 2

    button = [
        tk.Button(root, text=symbol, bg="light gray", borderwidth=0)
        for symbol in symbols
    ]

    # Minor changes to the for loop and if statements, use them if you want
    for i, _ in enumerate(symbols):
        if not i % 5:
            j += 1

        button[i].grid(row=j, column=i % 5, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
        button[i].configure(command=afterClickingBtn(lfd, button[i]["text"]))

    equal_button = tk.Button(root, text="=", bg="green", borderwidth=0)
    equal_button.grid(row=len(screen) + 6, column=3, columnspan=2, ipadx=60, ipady=10)

    return button, equal_button


def main():
    root = window()

    sc = screen(root)

    lfd = dataLabel(root, sc)

    # pass lfd into the buttons function
    btn = buttons(root, sc, lfd)

    # End of loop
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, consider changing the `buttons` function, as it currently runs 2 `for` loops unnecessarily, to this:

```
def buttons(root, screen, lfd):

    j = len(screen) + 2

    button = []
    for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
        b = tk.Button(root, text=symbol, bg="light gray", borderwidth=0)

        if not i % 5:
            j += 1

        b.grid(row=j, column=i % 5, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
        b.configure(command=afterClickingBtn(lfd, symbol))

        button.append(b)

    equal_button = tk.Button(root, text="=", bg="green", borderwidth=0)
    equal_button.grid(row=len(screen) + 6, column=3, columnspan=2, ipadx=60, ipady=10)

    return button, equal_button
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Good to hear. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you out